# XAML- how to make contents of grid automatically expand to fill window when it's resized?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, resize, presentation

I am displaying a web browser inside a Grid in the XAML of my application. The browser currently displays websites correctly, and allows the user full interaction with the website.

However, for some reason, the `<Grid>` in which I am displaying the browser is not expanding to fill the application window when it is resized, and it appears that the `CefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser` that I am using as my web browser is not expanding to fill the `<Grid>` in which I am displaying it...

When I run my application, it currently displays like this:

[image: screenshot of app]

The border of the `<Grid>` in which the browser is displayed is the green rectangle- as you can see, the browser has not expanded to fill this area. If I expand the window of my application by dragging one of its corners, the window resizes to display:

[image: second screenshot of app]

From the second screenshot, you can see that the application window has been resized, but the content has not expanded to fill the new size of the window. Why is this? How can I get the website to fill the size of the `browser` element in which I am displaying it, and how can I get the `browser` itself to fill all of the available space in the `<grid>` in which it's displayed?

The `XAML` I am using to display this in my GUI is:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" MinHeight="900" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1100" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Address="https://web.riviam.com" />
</Grid>
```

I tried editing the XAML to set the `<Grid>` Row & Column definitions to auto:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" MinHeight="900" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1100" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,-137,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Address="www.google.com" />
                    </Grid>
```

But this doesn't actually make a difference to how my application is displayed when it's run.

How can I resolve this, so that the `<Grid>` and its content are dynamically resized to fill the size of the window when it is resized?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I am struggling with a similar issue but in my case the content is too stretched vertically and it goes off screen preventing it to be scrolled.

Comment: Apologies, I left the company where I was working on this well over a year ago, so have not looked at the issue at all since then. I suspect I did not find a solution during the time that I was working on this particular piece of software, or I would have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" MinHeight="900" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1100" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
  <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser 
     Name="browser" 
     Height="{Binding ElementName=grdBrowserHost,Path=ActualHeight}" 
     Width="{Binding ElementName=grdBrowserHost,Path=ActualWidth}" 
     Grid.Row="0" Address="https://web.riviam.com" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- I've given this a go, and while it does make the content resize to fit the window when the window is resized (i.e. the green rectangle that marks the border of the `<grid>` expands to fit the window size), it also stops the content being displayed (i.e. the website is no longer displayed inside the `<grid>`... any idea why this is? Or any other suggestions?